# Python+matplotlib: custom linestyles

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm not satisfied with default set of linestyles, namely the size of line segments and the gap between them. I'd also want to have something like '-..', '-...', etc line patterns. Does anybody know how to customize it?

Best witches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`set_dashes`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/dash_control.html).

Comment: That is a little bit short answer for me. How can I change the default spacing of, lets say, dashes?

Comment: "set_dashes" above is a link to documentation.